# Gather financial data from yahoo with command IMPORTHTML()

Tags: google-sheets, importhtml

already at the beginning of the year I created a table (google sheet) that is intended for collecting financional data and creating reports from the yahoo server (Specifically, about 15 pages). I really spent a lot of time on it and tried not to burden yahoo server in any way. That's why I optimized over time and switched from reading individual values (IMPORTXML()) to reading entire tables (=IMPORTHTML()). I opened this document about once a week.

Lately, no pages or data on yahoo want to be loaded via google sheet. My command is writen the same way as before:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GAIN?p=GAIN&ncid=yahooproperties_peoplealso_km0o32z3jzm","Table",1)
```

But at the output I get: n/a "*Error
The resource at the address was not found*"

I think that Yahoo Finance is blocking my access.Or rather, not my approach but the approach from google sheet.

Does anyone have a similar problem?
Is there any way to work around this problem and get this data live another way?

I've tried other sites but I'm having the same problem there too.Sometimes I even wonder if Google Sheet is blocking it by chance. Unfortunately, I can't even download data from Google Finance, the problem here is that they don't provide current data on the market.

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Hi Rubén, 
First of all thank you for your link but I still have couple of questions regarding to this topic. I had them already before and I was hoping that somebody as you will answer me. Is there a way to contact you? (I have seen the link at your profile but it seems outdated) 
Thanks :)